# Yii2 Active Record casts zerofill column to int losing zeros

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have `User` table with zerofill primary `id`:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `id` int(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

My `User` model looks like:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        $identity = static::findOne(['id' => (int)$id]);

        var_dump($identity); //zeros are lost here
        exit;
    }
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }
}
```

Active Record casts `id` to `int` so I am getting: `1` for `00001`; `2` for `00002` etc. but I want to keep zeros and treat `id` as `string`.

Everything worked fine on x32 system, but we moved to x64. How to force Active Record to treat `id` as `string`?

Answer (score 0):

When Yii populates object within data from query result, it uses method

```
\yii\db\ColumnSchema::typecast
```

Means converts the input value according to [[phpType]] after retrieval from the database.

In your case ID is integer, so next rule will be used

```
    case 'integer':
        return (int) $value;
```

That's why **00001** converts to **1**

I found next solution, not the best but anyway

#### 1-st Solution

Every time when you try to get Id next function will be called

```
    public function getId()
    {
        return str_pad($this->id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

#### 2-nd Solution

Overrides afterFind and afterSave methods

```
    public function refreshUserId()
    {
        $this->id = str_pad($this->id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    public function afterFind()
    {
        parent::afterFind();

        $this->refreshUserId();
    }

    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

        $this->refreshUserId();
    }
```